# Randomly generate data under conditions for sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, random

As part of creating a machine learning exercise, I have an sqlite database that looks like this:
[image: diagram]
The "Pizza", "DateDimension" and "Customer" tables are already populated, there are 5 different pizzas and 10 customers.

How could I generate random data for the sales table, but give conditions to create a pattern?

For example, on Monday/Tuesday a random sales figure between 15 and 25, on the other days of the week a random sales figure between 10 and 20, between 20 and 30 on the weekend.

Knowing that for a day, a sale of 15 pizzas would be for the customer of ID=1 a sale of 2 pizzas of ID=2 and 4 pizzas of ID=3,
for the customer of ID=2 a sale of 3 pizzas of ID=2, and 
for the ID=3 customer a sale of 3 pizzas of ID=4 and 3 pizzas of ID=2.

This makes a total of 15 pizzas, of which 8 ID=2 pizzas, 4 ID=3 pizzas, 3 ID=4 pizzas, divided between three customers.

I don't know if I'm clear enough in my explanations, basically we need a random number of pizza sales for each day, and that this number is itself randomly split between the types of pizza and the customers, under certain conditions in order to follow a pattern in the number of sales per day.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following may be along the lines of what you want.

This first of all it creates sales for every 10 minutes in the date range (see comments) into an intermediate table (**initial_sales**) there will be some 10k or so. Each will have a random pizza, client and quantity.

Next another intermediate table, **daily_sales**, is generated from the **initial_sales** grouped by date (i.e. 1 row per date), in addition to the date the day of the week (0 = Sun ..... 6= Sat) (not really needed) more importantly though is the third column, this has a random number based upon the day of the week (the the CASE WHEN THEN END construct).

The **daily_sales** table is then queried and for each row sql is generated to insert data into the pizzeriasales table. e.g.

```
INSERT INTO pizzeriasales SELECT null,date(date),time(date),pizzaId,quantity,clientid FROM initial_sales WHERE date(date) = '2021-01-01' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 13;
INSERT INTO pizzeriasales SELECT null,date(date),time(date),pizzaId,quantity,clientid FROM initial_sales WHERE date(date) = '2021-01-02' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 25;
INSERT INTO pizzeriasales SELECT null,date(date),time(date),pizzaId,quantity,clientid FROM initial_sales WHERE date(date) = '2021-01-03' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 29;
INSERT INTO pizzeriasales SELECT null,date(date),time(date),pizzaId,quantity,clientid FROM initial_sales WHERE date(date) = '2021-01-04' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 20;
INSERT INTO pizzeriasales SELECT null,date(date),time(date),pizzaId,quantity,clientid FROM initial_sales WHERE date(date) = '2021-01-05' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 17;
INSERT INTO pizzeriasales SELECT null,date(date),time(date),pizzaId,quantity,clientid FROM initial_sales WHERE date(date) = '2021-01-06' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 10;
```

- Each will select random rows (*`ORDER BY random()`*) from the **initial_sales** for the pertinent date, the number of rows selected according to the number from the **daily_sales** table. The number being a random number between the lower number for the day of the week and the lower number plus 10.

As an example the is from the generated pizzeriasales table when grouped by the date, The first column shows the number of orders for the day.

```
(12, 1, '2021-01-01', '16:10:00', 5, 3, 8)
(23, 13, '2021-01-02', '01:40:00', 3, 3, 1)
(28, 36, '2021-01-03', '05:00:00', 3, 1, 5)
(16, 64, '2021-01-04', '10:10:00', 5, 2, 9)
(22, 80, '2021-01-05', '09:10:00', 4, 2, 7)
(14, 102, '2021-01-06', '10:10:00', 1, 1, 3)
(20, 116, '2021-01-07', '05:50:00', 5, 2, 4)
```

- note that other than the first value is the important value 12 shows that on 1/1/2021 that's how many sales were made (it looks like it was a Friday as 23 and 28 the next two dates were in the 20-30 range).
- **Note** you may notice that there was no need for the DateDimension table as long as the dates are in a format that is recognised by SQLite (https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

The whole thing Pyhton wise is :-

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("pizzasales.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

# Drop TABLES for clean TESTING environment
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pizzeriasales;")
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pizza")
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS client")
# Create and populate the pizza table
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pizza (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, price REAL);")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO pizza VALUES "
            "(null,'Meat Lovers', 10.00)"
            ",(null,'Hawian',12.50)"
            ",(null,'Neopolitan',11.00)"
            ",(null,'Margerita',9.00),(null,'standard',8.00);"
            )
# Create and populate the clieant table
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, firstName TEXT);")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO client VALUES "
            "(null,'Mary','Smith')"
            ",(null,'Fred','Bloggs')"
            ",(null,'Sarah','Bull')"
            ",(null,'Alan','Taylor')"
            ",(null,'Linda','James')"
            ",(null,'Barbara','Astley')"
            ",(null,'Mark','Jones')"
            ",(null,'Catherine','Seymour')"
            ",(null,'Charles','Page')"
            ",(null,'Alex','Howard');"
            )
# Create the pizzeriasales table to be populated later
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pizzeriasales (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date TEXT, hour TEXT, pizzaId INTEGER, quantity INTEGER, clientID INTEGER);")

# Create the intermediate initial sales (individual orders every 10 minutes with random pizza and client)
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS initial_sales;")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS initial_sales (date TEXT,pizzaId INTEGER, clientId INTEGER, quantity INTEGER);")
# Populate the table (some 10000 rows)
cur.execute("WITH "
            "cte_sales(date,pizzaId,clientId,quantity) "
            " AS (SELECT '2021-01-01 11:00'" # <<<<<<< date to start from
            ",abs(random() % (SELECT max(id) FROM pizza)) + 1" # <<<<<<<< random pizza
            ",abs(random() % (SELECT max(id) FROM client)) + 1" # <<<<<<<< random client
            ",abs(random() % 3) + 1" # <<<<<<<< random quantity
            " UNION ALL "
            " SELECT "
            "datetime(date,'+10 minute')"
            ", (1 + abs(random() % (SELECT max(id) FROM pizza)))"
            ",(1 + abs(random() % (SELECT max(id) FROM client)))"
            ",abs(random() % 3) + 1 FROM cte_sales "
            "WHERE date < '2021-03-01' " # <<<<<<< date to end on
            "LIMIT 10000" # <<<<<<<< secondary limit just in case
            ") "
            "INSERT INTO initial_sales SELECT * FROM cte_sales;"
            )

# Create the base dates i.e. 1 date with the number of sales that day
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS daily_sales_numbers;")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS daily_sales_numbers (date TEXT, day_in_week,number);")
# Now populate the daily_sales_numbers
cur.execute("WITH "
            "cte_base_dates(date,day_in_week,number) AS ("
            "SELECT "
            "date, "
            "strftime('%w',date),"
            "CASE "
            "WHEN CAST(strftime('%w',date) AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 15 + abs(random() % 11) "
            "WHEN CAST(strftime('%w',date) AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 10 + abs(random() % 11) "
            "ELSE 20 + abs(random() % 11) END "
            "FROM initial_sales "
            "GROUP BY date(date)"
            ") "
            "INSERT INTO daily_sales_numbers SELECT * FROM cte_base_dates;")

# Now prepare to build the pizzeriasales table
cursor = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM daily_sales_numbers;")
sql = []
for row in cursor:
    sql.append("INSERT INTO pizzeriasales " \
          "SELECT null,date(date),time(date),pizzaId,quantity,clientid " \
          "FROM initial_sales " \
          "WHERE "
               "date(date) = '" + (row[0])[0:10] #<<<<<<<< date as per the respective daily_sales row
               + "' ORDER BY random() " #<<<<<<<< random selection from the initial_sales
                 "LIMIT " + str(row[2]) #<<<<<<<< the number to include based upon the day of the week
               + ";")
for stmnt in sql:
    print(stmnt)
    cur.execute(stmnt)

# ALL done so show the number of rows in pizzeriasales and a per date basis
# note other data is from arbritary rows of the group (i.e. date)
conn.commit()
cursor = cur.execute("SELECT count(*),* FROM pizzeriasales GROUP BY date(date)")
for row in cursor:
    print(row)

cursor.close()
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```